# Major device number 0 in Linux

Tags: linux

What does it mean by using 0 as major device number? I tried 0; the device doesn't appear in `/dev` but it is listed in `/proc/devices`.

I created a char device with `register_chrdev`:

`register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &char_fops);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `0` means you're letting [register_chrdev()](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re941.html) choose a major number dynamically.

In this case, the function will return that number instead of `0`.

Comment: But I don't see anything under `/dev`. As written in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt , 0 means `Unnamed devices (e.g. non-device mounts)`. Does it mean nothing will be created in `/dev`?

Comment: @Amumu, you're not actually creating a device with major number `0`, since `register_chrdev()` will return a dynamic number. The device file not appearing in `/dev` may be normal on your system, did you try creating it yourself with `mknod`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi how did you get the register_chrdev() man page? I cannot man it. I assume it is under man 9 section with kernel functions, but I do not have this section, how did you obtain it?